# Google Chrome editing Javascript on the fly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've tried to ease my life by using Google Chrome's devtools and as I've tried to modify javascript of page on fly but it seems to behave unexpectedly

I have this function that is called every frame of the game

```
View.prototype.onHit = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.obstacles.length; i++) {
        if(this.obstacles[i].dealsDamage) {
            //deal damage
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

and when I open it on chromes "Sources tab" and pause execution and add something simple such as

```
console.log("hey");
```

it starts printing text "hey" on console as expected but the moment i modify some code such as the if check to

```
        if(!this.obstacles[i].dealsDamage) {
            //do something else
        } else {
            //deal damage
        }
```

inverting the behaviour and save the document, the code doesnt take effect and the logging source changes to View.js (old)

and anything I change after that doesn't affect the running javascript

[image: Screenshot from console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "(old)" script normally should only appear if the more complex changes are applied. Namely, if you change a function parameter number or start (and lamently stop) using a variable from outer scope.

If live edit fails to work in such simple use-case as you describe, it could be a good thing to file to http://crbug.com